# How to make a nested loop dynamic?

Tags: for-loop, dynamic, jstree

I have a problem:

For example, there are N number of generations, and I want to execute these generations in jstree like parents and children.

I can only use a fixed number of nested `for` loops. I don't know how to make it dynamic, i.e., I want to nest N `for` loops.

How can I do this?

I can only use a fixed number of nested loops, such as

```
for (i=0;i<=list1.size;i++){
    for (j=0;j<=list2.size;j++){
       // and some other  loops
    }
}
```

but this is static. I want to be able to dynamically execute N number of loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you can't have an arbitrary number of nested for-loops. The way to achieve this is by using [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

Here's an example:

```
function foo(list_of_lists) {
    // base case
    if (list_of_lists.length == 0) return;

    // otherwise, we'll get the head of the list, and continue
    list = list_of_lists[0];
    for (var idx = 0; idx <= list.length; idx++) {
        // do something

        // now recursively nest the next list in a for-loop
        foo(list_of_lists.splice(1));
    }
}
```

For N lists, this will build up nested for-loops that look like:

```
for (var idx = 0; idx <= list0.length; idx++) {
    for (var idx2 = 0; idx2 <= list2.length; idx2++) {
        for (var idx3 = 0; idx3 <= list3.length; idx3++) {
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a jstree specific solution - set `core.data` to a function - it will be executed each time a node needs to be loaded - that way you can have an "infinite" dynamic tree so to speak.